# Unable to dump LDAP database after changes

Tags: ldap, openldap

I added an attribute to my LDAP database by running

```
ldapmodify -QY EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f openssh-lpk.schema
```

as root, where `openssh-lpk.schema` contains this:

```
# Author: Eric AUGE <eau@phear.org>
#
# Based on the proposal of : Mark Ruijter
#
version: 1

dn: cn=openssh-lpk,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: add
cn: openssh-lpk
objectClass: olcSchemaConfig
olcAttributeTypes: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.24552.500.1.1.1.13 NAME 'sshPublicKey'
  DESC 'OpenSSH Public key'
  EQUALITY octetStringMatch
  SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.40 )
olcObjectClasses: ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.24552.500.1.1.2.0 NAME 'ldapPublicKey' SUP top AUXILIARY
  DESC 'OpenSSH LPK objectclass'
  MUST uid
  MAY sshPublicKey )

dn: cn={5}inetorgperson,cn=schema,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcObjectClasses
olcObjectClasses: ( 2.16.840.1.113730.3.2.2 NAME 'inetOrgPerson' DESC 'RF
 C2798: Internet Organizational Person' SUP organizationalPerson STRUCTURAL
 MAY ( audio $ businessCategory $ carLicense $ departmentNumber $ displayNam
 e $ employeeNumber $ employeeType $ givenName $ homePhone $ homePostalAddre
 ss $ initials $ jpegPhoto $ labeledURI $ mail $ manager $ mobile $ o $ page
 r $ photo $ roomNumber $ secretary $ uid $ userCertificate $ x500uniqueIden
 tifier $ preferredLanguage $ userSMIMECertificate $ userPKCS12 $ sshPublicK
 ey ) )
```

This works great – I'm able to modify users to add their public key details to their record, and then read that data from other clients.

Problems pop up when I try to back up the database using `slapcat` though:

```
5b044b38 olcObjectClasses: value #0 olcObjectClasses: AttributeType not found: "sshPublicKey"
5b044b38 config error processing cn={5}inetorgperson,cn=schema,cn=config: olcObjectClasses: AttributeType not found: "sshPublicKey"
slapcat: bad configuration file!
```

What have I done wrong that `slapcat` isn't able to see the definition for `sshPublicKey`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have modified `inetorgperson`. There was no need to do that.
Any number of `AUXILIARY` ObjectClasses can co-exists together (with one `STRUCTURAL` objectClass).

Your slapd may be okay if you restart it.

Comment: So add the `ldapPublicKey` class to the user along with `inetOrgPerson` and it will get that attribute?

Comment: Yes, exactly so.

Comment: Restarting did not work, I should have modified `inetOrgPerson` to its previous state using `ldapmodify` instead! The rest was right on though.